# Debugging ASP.NET Session Variables

Tags: .net, asp.net, debugging, session-variables

when the process run in the same browser, **it's easy** to open a new TAB and check the session variables there, **everything works fine** in this situation.

But when a webpage runs inside a `WebBrowser` Control (under Windows Forms) for example, **I can no longer get** any Session Variable that process is using.

> Does anyone have an idea on how to get the variables?

before I create a value to use Session Variables or File Output in the `web.config` :)

[image]

The image above is my **Debug window** but it's always empty when I run the web page from a different process :o(

---

**added**

Tracing is not an option as I get this from Trace:

[image]

The Debug window assigns that `List` to a `GridView` and shows up nicely.

Answer (score 2):

### ASP.NET Tracing Overview

ASP.NET tracing enables you to view diagnostic information about a single request for an ASP.NET page. ASP.NET tracing enables you to follow a page's execution path, display diagnostic information at run time, and debug your application. ASP.NET tracing can be integrated with system-level tracing to provide multiple levels of tracing output in distributed and multi-tier applications.

Inserted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx

Comment: but then I need to add `Trace="true"` to all my `.aspx` pages, adding `<trace enabled="true" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false" />` on the `web.config` is not enough ... not a good idea to change all code :(

Comment: >>I need to add Trace="true" to all my .aspx pages<< Why? You should not have to do this. By default, the Trace attribute is not added to the Page directive; therefore, setting in web.config should work for all pages without the Trace attribute. Why is enabling trace in the web.config not good enough?

Comment: only when I add the `Trace="true"` in `.aspx` page I get to see the trace info, and I just updated my question showing why Tracing is not an option.